# Trouble getting feature image from WordPress database

Tags: database, wordpress, image, post

I built a homepage for my WordPress site from scratch, copying the style of the theme Reflex (which I actually bought). I'm doing this because this way the site is faster, and uses a lot less bandwidth.

[Original site](http://designals.net) and [my build](http://designals.net/demo/demo)

But, I'm having trouble getting the featured images, I wrote some quick code just to work it out:

```
<img src="'.$thumb_img.'-200x200.jpg">
```

I add "-200x200" at the end of the url which I got from the database. I understand this is not the best way to do this, so the question is: what's the best practice here?

Also: am I right in rewriting WordPress' frontend for performance? Is there a better approach or solution that you can think ok?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(200, 200) ); ?>`

or, if you are not in the loop, try this:

```
<?php
$post_id = 54; //the post id that you want to display
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(200, 200) );
?>
```

Also, please see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: s976 @Bart, what I wanted to say is that I'm trying not to load all wordpress functions -such as get_the_post_thumbnail()-. My goal is to build a very light Wordpress front-end. I have thounsands of visitors daily and server bandwith goes to hundreds of gigabytes monthly.
I will continue using WP admin back-end.

For example: I'm getting posts directly from database, using PHP and SQL functions.

Comment: @GuillermoDelicia, If so, I don't see any reason not to go in your first way (although I would suggest you make your own get_thumb() function, so that your HTML code will be more elegant). But I want to ask you: have you try one of cache plugins for wordpress, like W3 Total Cache? Also, I don't think that the way you are going now decreases your bandwidth. Sure it can be more faster but the bandwidth will be the same, I think.